# Why isn't anything being outputted?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get the if-else statement to output something, but nothing is happening. Do you know what's wrong? Is it an error in the syntax? I am new to programming, so I would greatly appriciate any help. Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<title>Calculator</title>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
href="csp.css">
<script>
function computeGrade() {
var pg = document.getElementById("pg").value;
var fg = document.getElementById("fg").value;
var wof = document.getElementById("wof").value;
var og = (cg * (1 - (wof / 100)) + (gof * (wof / 100)))
var prettyOg = og.toFixed(2)
document.getElementById("og").innerHTML = "Overall Grade: " + prettyOg + "%";
}
let csp;
function outputGrade(og) {
if (og > 90) {
csp = "you have an A!";
} else if (og > 80) {
csp = "you have a B!";
} else if (og > 70) {
csp = "you have a C!";
} else if (og > 60) {
csp = "you have a D!";
} else {
csp = "you are failing...";
}
}
document.getElementById("cs").innerHTML = csp;
</script>
</head>
<h1> Overall Grade Calculator</h1>
<p>Current grade: <input id="pg" min="1" max="120"
onchange="computeGrade()"></input></p>
<p> Grade on Final: <input id="fg" min="1" max="120"
onchange="computeGrade()"></input></p>
<p>Final weight: <input id="wof" min="1" max="100"
onchange="computeGrade()"></input></p>
<p><button>Submit</button></p>
<h2 id="og"></h2>
<h3 id="cs"></h3>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am sure the error in the console would point to your problem. Learn to use your developer tools in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your `cg` and `gof` are not defined on here :

```
var og = (cg * (1 - (wof / 100)) + (gof * (wof / 100)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in calculating `og`. You're doing `var og = (cg * (1 - (wof / 100)) + (gof * (wof / 100)))` but there is no variable named `cg`. Chage `cg` to `fg` if it is a typo.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your variables `cg` and `gof` are typos and should instead be `pg` and `fg` respectively.

Also your function `computeGrade()` has already been closed with `}` right before you defined `let csp;`, you should remove that closing bracket.

Then the `outputGrade()` function is not called anywhere. it should be called right after defining it. Though that is also a waste of code, just eliminate that function and have one function which is `computeGrade()` that does the whole job

Also your `input` tags have closing `</input>` tags which is not right, the correct format is `<input/>`, all that has been covered in the code below

Then for your input, try using `onkeyup` to get a more visual output, but if that is your preference, `onchange` will only update the results when you move to a different input, the code below changes the output every time you change the values in the input fields and not when you change the focus of the input field you are writing on:

````
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Calculator</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="csp.css" />

        <script>
function computeGrade() {
var pg = document.getElementById("pg").value;
var fg = document.getElementById("fg").value;
var wof = document.getElementById("wof").value;
var og = (pg * (1 - (wof / 100)) + (fg * (wof / 100)))
var prettyOg = og.toFixed(2)
document.getElementById("og").innerHTML = "Overall Grade: " + prettyOg + "%";
let csp;
if (og > 90) {
csp = "you have an A!";
} else if (og > 80) {
csp = "you have a B!";
} else if (og > 70) {
csp = "you have a C!";
} else if (og > 60) {
csp = "you have a D!";
} else {
csp = "you are failing...";
}
document.getElementById("cs").innerHTML = csp;
}

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Overall Grade Calculator</h1>
        <p>Current grade:
            <input id="pg" min="1" max="120" onkeyup="computeGrade()"/>

        </p>
        <p>
            Grade on Final:

            <input id="fg" min="1" max="120" onkeyup="computeGrade()"/>

        </p>
        <p>Final weight:
            <input id="wof" min="1" max="100" onkeyup="computeGrade()"/>

        </p>
        <p>
            <button>Submit</button>
        </p>
        <h2 id="og"></h2>
        <h3 id="cs"></h3>
    </body>
</html>```
````